# Regex pattern search in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to extract values from a string based on a regex pattern in SQL Server. I have two patterns which can be boiled down to:

```
'string(int:int)'
'string(len=int):int+'
```

I need to extract one of the integers from the pattern - in case of the first pattern, integers from the bracket, from the second pattern, one of the integers in the end.

I would appreciate if someone has a good example of how to do something like this.

Comment: What are you trying to do and **why?** 1) those aren't valid regex patterns. `int` in a regex means the characters `i`, `n`, `t`. 2)There's no regex support in T-SQL and 3) Regex can't benefit from indexing, which makes it *really slow* of regular use in any database. If you want to search that data you should parse it *before* inserting it in the database, *any* database, and store it in proper fields

Comment: If this is a one-off operation, or you want this to extract the data into proper fields a) you should really do it on the client but b) SQL Server 2017 [added Python script support](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-python-in-sql-server-2017-to-obtain-advanced-data-analytics/) for machine learning. Nothing prevents you from using this for other reasons, but be aware that this really is an external script with a cross-process overhead. If you use Python scripts for frequent small calls, the overhead may be larger than the execution time itself

Comment: You can write a SQLCLR function in C# that uses .NET's `Regex` class internally. This won't fix the indexing problem though, and the memory used by the Regex is SQL Server's own. If you run a regex on a 1M row table, you'll end up parsing 1M values, keeping 1M parse trees *and* the parsed results in SQL Server's memory. All that will have to be GC'd afterwards. On the other hand, calling a SQLCLR function has no cross-process overhead

Comment: [This article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6529/sql-server-regex-clr-function/) explains how to create and deploy a Regex SQLCLR while this [Github repo](https://github.com/DevNambi/sql-server-regex) contains ready-made operators *and* specific instructions around security and deployment. Be careful though - writing `dbo.RegexMatch(...)` is easy, but it *will* scan the entire table and take up RAM that's multiple times the size of the source data. You'll have to make your regex as restrictive as possible, returning as little as possible

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make the patterns much clearer, to me at least.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so, for example, I have a column with value like "someVariable(2:6)", and I would like to extract the second element in the parenthesis as an integer - e.g. 6.  In the other case, I would have a column with a value of "someOtherVariable(len=2):123,456,789" and I would also like to extract the second value in the array - e.g. 456. Does this maybe make the situation more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of the `substring` and `charindex` as follows:

For first pattern you can use:

```
SUBSTRING(your_string,
          CHARINDEX(your_string,'(') + 1,
          CHARINDEX(your_string,':')-CHARINDEX(your_string,'(')-1
         )
```

For the second pattern you can use:

```
SUBSTRING(your_string,
          CHARINDEX(your_string,':')+1
         )
```